# javascript referring variables in clip:rect doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, variables, clip

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
img
{
position:absolute;
top:50px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<img id="myImg" src="w3javascript.gif" width="100" height="132">
<button type="button" onclick="clipImage()">Clip image</button>
<button type="button" onclick="clearClip()">Unclip image</button>

<script>
var a="50"
var b=30
var c=a-b

function clipImage()
{
document.getElementById("myImg").style.clip="rect(c+'px' 75px 75px 0px)";
}
function clearClip()
{
document.getElementById("myImg").style.clip="auto";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

BTW I just took this code from w3schools.:)
Sorry for not being specific in the question title but I wanted to know why can't I use the variables that I have created inside the `clip:rect`. Thanks for all the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your quote marks are off:

```
document.getElementById("myImg").style.clip = "rect(" + c + "px 75px 75px 0px)";
```

Comment: Because `c` is a variable. You can't just drop it into a string and hope it works. You need to break up the string using concatenation like I've done in my answer.